# ngrx/store Inject a store into a service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using ngrx/store v4.0.2, with Angular 4.3.3.

What I'm trying to do is access the store from within the service:

```ts
/********* Module *************/
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('feature1', reducers),
     //...
     ],
declarations: [ /*...*/ ],
exports: [],
providers: [
    AuthDataService
]
export class MyModule { }

/********* AuthDataService *************/
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthDataState } from '../reducers/auth';

export class AuthDataService {
    constructor(private state: Store<AuthDataState>){
        this.state.select(getIsLoggedIn).subscribe(in => {
              console.log("User 'loggedIn' is now set to:" + in);
         });
    }
}
```

However, I'm always getting `undefined`, while the store works just fine for components in the same module.

How can access the same store that's available to components, but from within the service?

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Lxq82

**Edit - issue fixed**
The issue was with the `getIsLoggedIn`. It was:

```
export const getIsLoggedIn = (state: AuthDataState) => state.IsLoggedIn;
```

It should've been:

```
export const getIsLoggedIn = createFeatureSelector<AuthDataState>('feature1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few errors in your plnkr

1.) You need to prefix the tracker service with `@Injectable()`

2.) Your `wasInjected` on the tracker service was asking `== null` and if it was not null, it would return false, and that did not make sense if you were asking the question "Was Injected". So I inverted that check.

Updated the plnkr here
http://plnkr.co/edit/KVLpHS

Comment: nope, that's not it... I've added plnkr link, have fun :)

Comment: Updated my answer, found issues in your plnkr. Also, I forked your plnkr (link above) and stripped out a bunch of stuff to find the errors. (store-router stuff and what not). Should have little bearing on the final answer.

Comment: Thanks... That fixed the plnkr, and I also found the issue with my selector - I was accessing the store directly, and I should've used `createFeatureSelector` (i.e. `createSelector`... in my original issue that I dumb down for SO, the issue was in the submodule that registered store with `StoreModule.forFeature`)